# Django - complicated ORM Query (related_set)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have model Car, Listing and Website.

```
class Listing..
    car = ForeignKey...
    website = ForeignKey...
    active = BooleanField...
```

I want to filter all `car` objects that have `listing` object on the given website but the `listing` needs to be active.

To get all `car` objects that have `listing` object on the given website:

```
website = ...
Car.objects.filter(listings__website__in=website)
```

But how do I filter out inactive listings?

I want something like:

```
website = ...
Car.objects.filter(listings[only_active]__website__in=website)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do an extra condition on your filter:

```py
Car.objects.filter(listings__website__in=website, listings__active=True)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it return also the cars that have at least one `listing__website` matched and at least one (any) listing active (any listing, not necessarily the listing of the particular website)?  Which is a superset of the results wanted.

Comment: It won't. This code will work as per your need. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships